# Subversion SlikSvn unable to connect to a repository

Tags: svn

I  have a svn repository, I could connect using TortoiseSVN GUI and download SVN files. Now when I use Slik SVN (subversion 1.7) command, it says it could not connect to a repository.

I could do plink.exe -i private_key.ppk username@server, it prompt password in command window and I could log in. But I change the config in %APPDATA%\Subversion, in the tunnel section, I put
ssh = c:/pathTo/plink.exe -i c:/pathTo/privatekeyfile.ppk

I try svn co svn+ssh://server/toRepository, it always saying could not connect to a repository. The private/public key using openssh with passphrase.

Any hints??

Comment: Which protocol (**exactly**) you used in TSVN?! Do *the same* with Slik and don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

1. Ability to successfully ssh into remote host (repository-host) does **not** mean automagically, that `svn+ssh://` will work - "SVN over SSH" must be specially configured and enabled at server-side
2. Use the same protocol, as for TortoiseSVN, in SlikSVN
3. You *may* connect TSVN to repository over proxy, defined only TSVN settings (and not reflected in Subversion config) - `TortoiseSVN` - `Settings` - `Network`